# Can I set matplotlib savefig() options for a whole notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am working in a jupyter notebook that produces several figures, each of which gets saved to an svg file.

In each call to `savefig()` I am using `bbox_inches='tight'` as such:

```py
ax.figure.savefig(path.join(graphics_dir,'filename1.svg'),bbox_inches='tight')
ax.figure.savefig(path.join(graphics_dir,'filename2.svg'),bbox_inches='tight')
...
```

Is there some configuration setting I can use to set `bbox_inches='tight'` for the whole notebook so I don't have to pass it in every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rcParameter`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)

```
savefig.bbox   : tight
```

This can be set in the [matplotlib rc file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file), or via code on top of your notebook, like

```
plt.rcParams["savefig.bbox"] = "tight"
```